# Why does server block when loading XML from a NetworkStream?

Tags: c#, xml, networking, xmldocument, networkstream

I have a simple client and server in C#.  The goal is for the client to send an XML document to the server, and then the server should respond with a different XML document.  The server is blocking when I try to receive the input/request XML with XmlDocument.Load(NetworkStream).

Server:

```
        TcpListener t = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 4444);
        t.Start();
        TcpClient c = t.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream s = c.GetStream();
        XmlDocument req = new XmlDocument();
        req.Load(s);

        string respString = "<response><data>17</data></response>";
        XmlDocument resp = new XmlDocument();
        resp.LoadXml(respString);
        resp.Save(s);
```

Client:

```
        TcpClient t = new TcpClient("localhost", 4444);
        NetworkStream s = t.GetStream();

        string reqStr = "<request><parameters><param>7</param><param>15</param></parameters></request>";
        XmlDocument req = new XmlDocument();
        req.LoadXml(reqStr);

        req.Save(s);

        XmlDocument resp = new XmlDocument();
        resp.Load(s);

        Console.WriteLine(resp.OuterXml);
```

I tried adding a Flush() in the client after it saves the request XmlDocument to the stream, but that didn't seem to help.  Originally I tried having the server read all of the input from the client to a MemoryStream, but then I found that there was no way to signify to the server that all the input was done without disconnecting, which meant that then the client couldn't read its input.

I can send XML input to the server from a file with netcat and everything works fine.  This works whether I use XmlDocument.Load(NetworkStream) in the server, or read all the input into a MemoryStream.  What is it that netcat is doing in this case that I am not doing in my C# client, and how do I do it in C#?  Should I be going about this differently?

Comment: What about firewall?

Comment: There can be lots of reasons why the stream is being blocked like a firewall or virus checker blocking the port number.   I would first attempt to see if you can download xml using an IE web-browser manually.  If you can then it is not a firewall issue.  I would then use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddle to capture IE download and compare results with your  c# application.  Usually the issue is the http header in c# application need to be modified to match the IE results.

Comment: It is not the firewall or a network issue - netcat from the same machine can send the required input.  I don't see how I could test this scenario with IE, because IE will not send an XML request to my server.

Comment: Also, Windows firewall is already off.

Comment: @jdweng there is no http involved here.

Comment: TCP can still be seen on sniffer.  You can sniffer the netcat command to see what port it is using.  It may be using a windows method that doesn't use TCP.  Windows PC have an internal method for sending data that is not compatible with TCP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tcp connection is bidirectional, and you can close one half of it while still having the other half open. In this case, you can close client to server half after sending all data, and then you can receive response over server to client half still. You can do it for your example like this:

```
TcpClient t = new TcpClient("localhost", 4444);
NetworkStream s = t.GetStream();
string reqStr = "<request><parameters><param>7</param><param>15</param></parameters></request>";
XmlDocument req = new XmlDocument();
req.LoadXml(reqStr);
req.Save(s);
// important line here! shutdown "send" half of the socket connection.
t.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
XmlDocument resp = new XmlDocument();
resp.Load(s);
Console.WriteLine(resp.OuterXml);
```

Don't forget dispose network stream on a server's side after you sent all data:

```
TcpListener t = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 4444);
t.Start();
TcpClient c = t.AcceptTcpClient();
using (NetworkStream s = c.GetStream()) {
    XmlDocument req = new XmlDocument();
    req.Load(s);                
    Console.WriteLine("Got request: {0}", req.OuterXml);
    string respString = "<response><data>17</data></response>";
    XmlDocument resp = new XmlDocument();
    resp.LoadXml(respString);
    resp.Save(s);
}
```

Actually if whole communication is single request followed by single response - you can use this technique instead of custom protocols over tcp (remember to use timeouts and properly dispose your streams and tcp clients).

Otherwise, remember that network stream is kind of open connection between client and server - it does not have explicit "end". When you are doing XmlDocument.Load - it will read until it is possible (that is until Read returns with 0 bytes read), so it blocks in your case. You should define your own protocol over tcp, so that you yourself can define the message boundary. Simple way would be - first 4 bytes define the length of the following message. So you read first 4 bytes and then read until that length is reached or timeout occurs.

Comment: @skiphoppy see the update, I think it answers your question in a more complete way.

Comment: Thanks, @Evk, I think the Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send) may be what I have been missing.  I stumbled in Shutdown() yesterday but didn't realize there were parameters to tell it to only shut down one side.

Comment: Rats.  When I try Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send), it gets me a little further, but then when the client tries to read what the server is sending, it gets "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."  Which sounds like both sides got shut down.

Comment: Updated my answer with server code I used for testing (which works fine without any errors). Maybe you forgot to close server side (did not dispose NetworkStream) or something.

Comment: Yep - when I close it on the server side instead of just letting the server process, I'm good.  Thank you - you have solved my problem!  I knew it had to be possible; just didn't know how to explicitly end one side of the connection.  Yesterday I got shut down on another question for asking a variant of this; I was told it was impossible.